# Esperar a un cambio en la base de datos para devolver resultado en web api controller

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, api, web, controller

He programado unos Web Api controllers para alimentar una aplicación móvil con datos...

En uno de los controles debo esperar a que una columna en una tabla para un ID específico cambie para devolver una respuesta (en este caso un JSON)

Estaba tratando de usar SqlDependency pero no puedo hacer que funcione... En los ejemplos que he visto se activa un triger cuando cambia la base de datos, pero lo que realmente necesito es esperar a que cambie, igual no logro nada.. Podría hacer una llamada de "Select Status" cada tantos segundos, pero se que no es la forma adecuada...

Necesito algo como esto:

```
int RequestStatus = await CheckRequestStatusChangeOnDB(RequestID);

//Esperar hasta que CheckRequestStatusChangeOnDB detecte que hubo un cambio y devuelva un valor

if (RequestStatus == 1)
                {//hacer algo}
if (RequestStatus == 2)
                {//hacer algo}
if (RequestStatus == 0)
                {//no hubo cambio en la tabla (después de cierto tiempo sin respuesta)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta respuesta la puse en otro hilo, pero creo que funciona perfectamente también para ti.

Como estás utilizando SQL Server recomiendo leer sobre SQL Server Query Notification https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx

También revisa Apache ActiveMQ es gratis y te puede ayudar en este caso.

Answer (score 0):

La solución más sencilla es usar **Ajax Polling**, que consiste en hacer un request a tu api cada cierto tiempo de manera indefinida hasta que obtengas el resultado esperado.

Imagina que tienes una aplicación de transacciones que deben ser verificadas por un tercero antes de marcarlas como completadas.

1. Un cliente realiza una transacción y se marca como pendiente ya que ésta debe ser verificada por un tercero.

   Transaction ID: 1a2s3d4f
   Transaction Status: Pending
2. Tu app hace un request (Poll) a la transacción (`GET transactions/1a2s3d4f`) y obtienes que la transacción está pendiente.

   Transaction ID: 1a2s3d4f
   Transaction Status: Pending
3. Tu app hace otro request (Poll) a la transacción (`GET transactions/1a2s3d4f`) y obtienes que la transacción aún está pendiente.

   Transaction ID: 1a2s3d4f
   Transaction Status: Pending
4. Se ejecuta un background job que verifica si la transacción fue aprobada por el tercero y le modifica el status a completado.
5. Tu app hace el mismo request (`GET transactions/1a2s3d4f`) y ahora recibes que la transacción ha sido completada.

   Transaction ID: 1a2s3d4f
   Transaction Status: Completed